# Use XSL to define indenting for specific elements

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am writing an XSL which creates an XSL-FO that contains some literary references. One problem I have encountered is in properly treating the triple em dash in references. When the same author is repeated in two sequential references, a triple em dash is used in place of the author's name in the second reference. The em dashes should be closed up.

The XSL-FO method I have found for achieving this is by using fo:character in place of the em dashes, with a negative letter spacing. Unfortunately, when I output the FO, each fo:character element is placed on its own line, which I think the FO processor interprets as white space. So my em dashes end up spaced out. If I go into the FO and put them on the same line, they look as they should.

The easy solution to my problem is to set the indent attribute of xsl:output to no. However, my FO file is very long and that makes it unreadable. I'm wondering if there is any other method for forcing indent rules on specific elements. (I'm open to another method of handling this in XSL-FO, but I understand that should be a different SO question).

Here is the template that adds the fo:character tags.

```
<xsl:template match="ref/text()[matches(., '^———.')]">
    <fo:character character="—" letter-spacing="-.2em"/><fo:character character="—" letter-spacing="-.2em"/><fo:character character="—" letter-spacing="-.2em"/><xsl:copy-of select="substring-after(., '———')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Sample short XML:

```
<document>
    <ref>———. <i>Hamlet</i>. Ed. Harold Jenkins. London: Methuen, 1982. Print.</ref>
</document>
```

Snippet of the output that I get with indent="yes":

```
<fo:block start-indent="11pt"
        text-indent="-11pt">
    <fo:character character="—" letter-spacing="-.2em"/>
    <fo:character character="—" letter-spacing="-.2em"/>
    <fo:character character="—" letter-spacing="-.2em"/>. <fo:inline font-style="italic">Hamlet</fo:inline>. Ed. Harold Jenkins. London: Methuen, 1982. Print.</fo:block>
```

I'm using XSL 2.0 and Saxon-HE. Is conditional indenting possible, or should I find another solution?

Comment: What FO processor are you using? FOP?

Comment: Currently, XSL Formatter (but an older version, 4).

Comment: Fine. Please try the `fo:block` attributes I have mentioned - let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sympathize with the fact that your FO output is very long, and failure to indent it makes it difficult to read. I struggle sometimes with a similar problem when generating TeX code: I need to make it human-readable for debugging purposes, but sometimes that changes the semantics of the generated code.

However, there's a fundamental conflict here: FO considers text nodes, including whitespace, in its input document to be significant, and indeed it must in order to work properly. So if you tell your FO-generator stylesheet to insert whitespace (via indent="yes"), it's going to be treated as significant.

You already know this and are asking how to avoid the indentation selectively. I don't think there's a way to do that in Saxon. But I would suggest a few other angles:

1. What happens if you generate the `<fo:block>` with `xml:space="default"`? The FO processor is not obligated to respect that declaration, but it may be worth a try.
2. You could fork your process to produce two outputs, one human-readable (generated with `indent="yes"`) and one that's intended for consumption by the FO processor (generated w/o indent).
3. You could turn off the built-in indenting (`indent="yes"`) in your stylesheet, and then "roll your own" fully-customized indentation process. The latter could be a part of the same XSLT stylesheet; or it could be a completely separate tool, whichever meets your needs.

Comment: I think in the end I'm going to go with a variation on option 2. I determined that doubling the negative letter-spacing (-.4 rather than -.2) fixes the problem when the XML is indented (but looks wrong when it's not). So, I turned that value into a variable and I'll just change it depending on whether I'm in a dev/debug phase or an implementation phase. Thank you for the suggestions; I'm going to try number 3 one of these days.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to compromise readability in order to get correct output.

Try to change the treatment of linefeeds not globally (i.e comprehensively, by having `indent="no"`), but on the level of `fo:block`:

```
<fo:block start-indent="11pt"
        text-indent="-11pt"
        linefeed-treatment="ignore">
    <fo:character character="—" letter-spacing="-.2em"/>
    <fo:character character="—" letter-spacing="-.2em"/>
    <fo:character character="—" letter-spacing="-.2em"/>. <fo:inline font-style="italic">Hamlet</fo:inline>. Ed. Harold Jenkins. London: Methuen, 1982. Print</fo:block>
```

That should cause any linefeeds inside this block to be ignored. Of course, this means that you'd have to identify the blocks that should contain the "-" characters and add this attribute.

See: http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#linefeed-treatment for the relevant part of the specification. Also, there are attributes that specify how your FO processor deals with whitespace, namely `whitespace-treatment`, `white-space-collapse` and `white-space` (which summarizes a bunch of other attributes).

Any of the above attributes might be involved in your case. The exact workings depend on your FO processor and version.

A good resource to get an overview of the technical capabilities might also be: http://www.schemacentral.com/sc/fo11/a-linefeed-treatment-1.html.

Comment: Thank you for this. Unfortunately, none of these attributes did quite what I needed (white-space-collapse fixed the em dashes, but also removed all other spaces in the reference). This was exactly what I need to look at, though, to confirm for myself what was possible.